# How to use default Gradle file?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

When creating new projects with Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1, it automatically starts downloading Gradle files each and every time, is there anyway I could manually add the Gradle zip into the Android Studio? so I won't have to download it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle distributions are automatically cached after downloading, so until you change the gradle version your project uses (by manually editing `gradle-wrapper.properties`), it shouldn't download the same gradle distribution more than once.